unwind on Arm after a division by zero
I'm doing some unwinding tests on an ARM processor. I'm using libunwind and a C file which is compiled by using the CFLAGS -g -O0 -funwind-tables
In this C file, I have a main function which is called a test function, test function is calling another function where the division by zero is present.
I'm using a loop when unw_step is used. But unfortunately the backtrace stopped at this symbol __aeabi_ldiv0 (unw_step return 0), and I do not understand why I can go further in the backtrace.
Has anyone already faced this issue ? If yes, is it normal behavior ?
Thank you in advance for those who will answer me.
I have tried with another defect (like a segfault) and it works as expected. I was expecting the same kind of result for the division by 0.

Edit your question and post your code as text.  Descriptions of code are all but useless - will an automobile mechanic be able to fix your car if all he knows is, "It makes a noise."?
